# guys, i am new to ML. i was trying to make linear regression model on fmri dataset. while passing x_train,y_train code , it shows me following error

Tags: machine-learning

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as nm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        
df=sns.load_dataset('fmri')

x=df[['timepoint','subject']]
y=df['signal']

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression 

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5388\1414350166.py in <module>
----> 1 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

~\Anaconda3\envs\MACHINELEARNING\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in train_test_split(test_size, train_size, random_state, shuffle, stratify, *arrays)
   2415         raise ValueError("At least one array required as input")
   2416 
-> 2417     arrays = indexable(*arrays)
   2418 
   2419     n_samples = _num_samples(arrays[0])

~\Anaconda3\envs\MACHINELEARNING\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    376 
    377     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
--> 378     check_consistent_length(*result)
    379     return result
    380 

~\Anaconda3\envs\MACHINELEARNING\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    332         raise ValueError(
    333             "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: %r"
--> 334             % [int(l) for l in lengths]
    335         )
    336 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [53940, 1064]
```

Comment: This example references a variable `X` which is not defined. (The variable `x` is defined, but Python is case sensitive.) Is this a typo, or is the variable `X` defined somewhere? (If you're using jupyter, you may want to press "Restart Kernel" to make sure there are not any variables hanging around from previous versions of this code.)

Comment: Thanks Nick ODell
you are right. X was not defined properly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Nick ODell pointed out in the comments about X not being defined, the ValueError you're seeing is because you are calling train_test_split on two different sized arrays. Your X and y inputs to train_test_split need to be the same sizes, here they are 53940 and 1064 respectively. In other words, for every input, you need exactly one output. hth.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Brewmaster321.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please check `x`in `x=df[['timepoint','subject']]` versus `X` in `train_test_split(X...`

However,

```
df=sns.load_dataset('fmri')
```

This should be

```
df=pd.read_csv('fmri') # but I don't know the format for this data set
```

Just be sure that the script is run from the same directory as `fmri`

A small example data set would be cool. You are using both `sns` and `matplotlib` for plotting, but `ins` will not load a data set thats `pandas`

Comment: Thank you  M_183

Comment: Upvotes or acceptance is always preferred to thanks @brijesh